# Code injection with PHP

Tags: php, code-injection

I'm aware of how to protect against SQL injections & stuff & validating user input... but was wondering if you are taking data from a user input field & the data is a string how safe is this data to use inside your code for stuff like:

```
if ($i == $_POST['userinput']) {
    ....
}
```

The above is just an example at trying to get across my question at asking what steps you need to take & in what circumstances.

Obviously it wouldn't work in the above instance, but just trying to prevent people doing something like an include('whatever.php'); etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a comparison against a variable, like you show, is not dangerous in itself, so there's nothing to worry about there.

User input becomes potentially dangerous when *used*, in an include statement, in a database query, in a file name, in an `eval()` call, in a HTML page, etc. every one of those uses has ***one*** correct sanitation method.

Answer (score 1):

comparing to user provided variables is fine, they are simply handled as string. regarding your `include('whatever.php')` example, use whitelisting to protect against it:

```
if(!in_array($userinput, array('libs.php', 'my.php'))) {
  die('sorry pal');
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I thought so, just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are calling `eval` or similar functions that **create and run actual PHP code** from a string like `create_function`, you generally don't need to worry about actual code injection.

As you've already pointed out, you do need to be careful when performing includes or calling functions based directly on user input.  The fact that you knew this means that you're probably already well-prepared in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Data coming from users is *potentially* dangerous, but it doesn't mean it's dangerous *always* -- it depends on what you do with it.

While filtering/whitelisting/sanitizing data is always good practice, the absolute minimum you must do is avoid using it directly to do things that interact actively with the environment: dealing with the filesystem (includes, fopen, file_(get|put)_contents, etc.), the database, generating HTML output and so on.

Of course, different cases call for different measures: for example, there is no point in using (as I often see) `htmlspecialchars()` when building database queries -- that function's purpouse is to avoid code injection in browser output, so it should be used for that.

In short there is no magic one-sentence answer, you have to know what's dangerous and when, and act accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

As a string by itself, it is fine.It is still safer to addslashes to ensure that symbols such as `'` and `"` do not clash. It's mainly a danger to SQL Databases.

Comment: please **don't** advise to use `addslashes`!

Comment: Addlashes in itself adds no safety whatsoever.

Comment: `addslashes()` is the equivalent of using an overcooked spaghetti noodle as a seat belt in your car.